# How to pass data from mongo database to html email in python to show a table based summary

Tags: python, html, mongodb, twitter-bootstrap, html-email

I'm am trying to create an html based email using python. So in my email content I want to create a html table to display the list of contents of mongodb collection contains data about different customer added within last 24 hrs.

How do I insert json response got from mongo into html email with python . The json response I'm using here is data.

```
 data = {
   u'FirstName': u'ABC',
   u'LastName': u'XYZ',
   u'Company': u'KBS',
   u'added_time': datetime.datetime(2016, 12, 12, 12, 12, 20, 207000),
   u'ID': 123
 }
```

Below is what have so far:-

```
import sys
import json
import smtplib
from pymongo import MongoClient
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText

sender = 'abc@abc.com'
receivers = 'abc@abc.com'

# Create message container - the correct MIME type is multipart/alternative.
msg = MIMEMultipart('alternative')
msg['Subject'] = "TEST"
msg['From'] = sender
msg['To'] = receivers

client = MongoClient('mongodb://localhost:27017/')
db = client.abc

data = []
### Get all the customer added within last 24 hrs
for cust in db.customer.find{"added_time": {"$gt" : dt, "$lt" : datetime.now() }}):
    data.append(cust)

print data 
# Create the body of the message (a plain-text and an HTML version).
text = "Hi! this is auta geneated mail"
html = """\
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
    <table>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
"""

part1 = MIMEText(text, 'plain')
part2 = MIMEText(html, 'html')

msg.attach(part1)
msg.attach(part2)
```

Comment: Where exactly are you having trouble? You have the data, what is the issue you having in inserting it into the HTML?

Comment: @DanielRoseman Yeah have the data but not able to insert the data into table and get the data in tabular form in email.

Comment: But why not? What did you try? It's just a string.

Comment: Im not so good with html.. Not usre how to loop through all the data and add it to table. how to use the variables inside html tags.

Comment: @DanielRoseman The data which is shown above is just one entry similary i have 50+ entry. So i need to show all of them in a table with pagination. So that is where i'm not able to do it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use an ordered dict so the json objects don't move around

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
from collections import OrderedDict

client = MongoClient('mongodb://localhost:27017/', document_class=OrderedDict)
```

And instead of writing your own table parser, use an already made module like [json2html](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/json2html/) (the power of python ;) )

---

The library will convert all fields in the dict to a table, so you will need to make a new dict of only required fields

```
json_data = {...}
required  = ['a','b','c']
relevant = {k.upper():json_data[k] for k in required}
```

and for multiple rows, need a list of dicts

```
table_json = [{...}, {...}, ...]
```

Comment: Looks good.


       html = """\
        <html>
  <head></head>
        <body>
           json2html.convert(json = datat)
        </body>
    </html>
   """

This  is how am I suppsoed to add in my code

Comment: Try this.  """\ <html> <head></head> <body> %s </body> </html> """ % (json2html.convert(json = data))

Comment: can I see the full dict. You will need to remove the ID key/value pair. Just use the del key word. E.g.  del data["_id"]

Comment: Is it possible to add only required fields in table than all the fields

Comment: It worked !! 
Few more query i have is it possible to make table header row colouered with json2html and table Header name capital.. If i want to do such things ?

Comment: great. I'm not sure they support css styling yet. I haven't used it extensively. you may need to read up on how to add styling to email templates. It will require learning some html/css

Comment: ass for upper case, just make your keys uppercase... see edit

Comment: is it possibile to add Key field replace with my own Table heading  ?